# Chrome Contacts Search no longer working

Tags: google-chrome, search, contacts

I am no longer able to search for a contact using the contacts search bar, yet if I initiate a new email from Gmail, the auto-complete will complete the addressee search as always. I have Firefox loaded also and it exhibits the same behavior, only the new email auto-complete will *not* work. I am using Windows 10, version 22H2, OS build 19045.2965, and Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

I am a senior, non-techie. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Hello, could you be more specific? Which contacts search bar?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem for months, and I tried the following, and it worked.

If you reset Chrome, your search engine and start page will revert to default. In addition, all installed extensions and cache will be gone.

As for settings, they will be restored to the default values. Of course, bookmarks and saved password won’t be affected by this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, Myrna. I am also a new user with this my first question. I tried to answer your question with an attached picture, but I could not figure out how to do it. Sorry. At any rate, my problem seems to have self-corrected as my search functions are now working again. Thanks.